# output impedance without small signal model

Tags: transistors, mosfet, integrated-circuit, analog, circuit-analysis

For the mosfet in the figure below, we have:

> ```
> 1. routd = rds(1+gm*rs)
> 2. routs = (1/gm)*(1 + rd/rds)
> ```

Actually, it is not difficult to derive these formulas. However, is there an intuitive way to get this without drawing small signal model?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - there is another (intuitive) approach based on feedback theory.
As we know - the resistor Rs (I am using a large symbol because it is an ohmic resistive part) provides negative current-controlled voltage feedback. According to feedback theory, the output resistance in this case is always increased by the factor **(1-loop gain LG)**.

For the given circuit the loop gain is **LG=-gmRs** and, as a result, we have **r,out,d=r,ds(1+gmRs)=r,ds(1+Rs/r,e)** with r,e=1/gm. The symbol r,e  is used sometimes instead of 1/gm because 1/gm is the input resistance at the source node for common gate stages.

Similarly, we can find the expression for **r,out,s** if we replace Rs by Rd and r,e by r,ds. It is a bit uncommon to consider - as far as the output resistance at the source is concerned - the small feedback effect caused by Rd (small loop gain LG=-Rd/r,ds because r,ds is much larger). Nevertheless, that is the way we arrive at the given expression for r,out,s  .